# JAutoDoc evaluation of @Annotations?

Tags: annotations, jautodoc

I would like to know whether it is possible to examine the contents of method (fields) annotations through JAutoDoc.

```
public interface A {
  @MyAnnotation(attribute=false)
  String getSomeValue();
}
```

In the resulting javadoc, I would like to output a value based on the annotation attribute, `attribute` in this case. It seems simple enough to build the regexp and the template with `#if(...)`. Everything works fine while it's entered in the preview window but in my code it's not working: JAutoDoc seems to ignore the annotation alltogether. Is there any way to convince it to look at beyond method/field signature?

I tried several levels of inserting the template, e.g. a standalone template in the method hierarchy or a sub-template of the "Returns other" template.

Thanks, Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JAutodoc at version 1.10.0, a template like this can be built:

```
#if(${e.hasAnnotation('MyAnnotation')})
#set($vc=$e.getAnnotation('MyAnnotation'))
#if(${$vc.getValue('mandatory')})
The value is mandatory.
#else
The value is optional.
#end
```

Answer (score 1):

JAutodoc doesn't support annotations directly, but maybe this template fits your needs:

```
/**
#set($found = 'false')
#if(${e.getMember().getMember().getAnnotations()})
    #foreach($a in ${e.getMember().getMember().getAnnotations()})
    #if(${a.getElementName()} == 'MyAnnotation')
        #set($found = 'true')
        Annotation found: ${a.getElementName()}
        #foreach($vp in ${a.getMemberValuePairs()})
        #if(${vp.getMemberName()} == 'attribute')
            #if(${vp.getValue()} == 'false')
            attribute is false
            #elseif(${vp.getValue()} == 'true')
            attribute is true
            #else
            attribute is ${vp.getValue()}
            #end
        #end
        #end
    #end
    #end
#end
#if($found == 'false')
 * No Annotation.
#end
 */
```

Comment: Where should the template be put? Putting it at the template "Return others" doesn't work.

Comment: For your example above the "Getter" template matches.

Comment: The newest jautodoc plugin supports annotations now.